# pass parameters to an action including the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am new to MVC and i'm trying to pass the parameter and the Model that was input from the user.

i want to pass them to the action on button click.

here is my Action code.

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult SaveData(string param, MyObjectModel model)
{ ... }
```

on my View:

```
function PassParam()
{ ... }
```

and my button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Generate" onclick="PassParam();" />
```

what is the best way to pass a string and a model to an action??

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: sorry, forgot to include. the question. what is the best way to pass a string and a model to an action??

Answer (score 4):

use jQuery and send a POST with an actual JSON object:

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/Action",
    type: "POST",
    data: { param: "someValue", model: { YourModelProp1:  "text", YourModelProp2:  12345 }}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a simple way of just adding another attribute to MyObjectModel and then pass the param to the new attribute so when the page submits, the model will be passed to the controller with the new attribute.